# Jquery updating link with href value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
  $("#deleteorderb").click(function()
  {
    $("#deleteorder").attr('href','/deleteorder.php?id=' + $('#deleteorderb').val());
  })
});
```

```html
<a onclick="jQuery('#modal-2').modal('show');" id="deleteorderb" name="deleteorderb" 
   value="<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-icon icon-left">
     Cancel
</a>
```

When I click the link, it opens a popup modal, which has a but of text saying are you sure you want to delete, and then there's a link, herf, I want to update that herf to equal the the other href's value which will be a database query to get the id. the ink updates with the above but not the id. I have checked the source code and the a hrefs value IS set.

Comment: What is the value of $('#deleteorderb').val()?

Comment: value="<?php echo $r['id']; ?>"  it is being set I've checked the source.

Comment: What llya said--if #deleteorderb is, in fact, a link (an anchor tag), it has no value--no .val(). If it is supposed to have the original links href appended to it, you can get it using $('#deleteorderb').attr('href')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to grab element `attribute` value, so instead of

```
$('#deleteorderb').val()
```

try

```
$('#deleteorderb').attr('value')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, *note the use of .attr("value") not .val():

```
<a onclick="dialog();" id="deleteorderb" name="deleteorderb" value="<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-icon icon-left"> Cancel</a>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#deleteorderb").click(function() {
            var a = $('#deleteorderb').attr("value");
            var link = "/deleteorder.php?id=" + a;
            $("#deleteorder").attr("href", link);
        });
        function dialog() {
            $('#modal-2').modal('show');
        };
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value attribute is normally used on form fields. So in your case it would make sense to use a data attribute as follows:

```
<a  id="deleteorderb" name="deleteorderb" data-value="<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" .....
```

And in your JavaScript you could access it like so:

```
$('#deleteorderb').data('value');
```

**BONUS**

I would not recommend using *inline* JS. Instead just use jQuery to setup a click event listener in your DM ready callback:

```
$('#deleteorderb').on('click', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#modal-2').modal('show');
});
```

Updated html:

```
<a 
    id="deleteorderb" 
    name="deleteorderb" 
    data-value="<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" 
    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-icon icon-left">
        Cancel
</a>
```